# CSS filter blur animation does not work correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, blur

#### Original Intention

- After clicking a button, have a modal popup on the center of the screen, while the original page content nicely blurs away in the background.

#### Result

- Everything works as intended in Chromium and Safari, while the blur animation stutters in an awesomely ugly manner in Firefox.
- EDIT:  It turned out that the problem do not affect Firefox consistently. I switched from Mac to Windows and on the latter it magically works...

#### Tests & Research

- I couldn't have found anything of value on the Web. As I understand, filter blur either works for other developers or don't.
- And then I realise that this issue does not occur when there is just a couple of elements to blur.
- So I reason, that if I apply filter blur with animation to a container holding the original content of the page, the web browser has a lot of elements to blur.
- Based on my home tests, the problem affects Mac, but does not occur on Windows. I reckon the issue might come from poor integration between Mac embedded graphic chipset vs. Firefox?
- All in all, I have constructed the below test case. It shows (on my Mac), that Chromium and Safari animates filter blur swiftly, while Firefox stutters and shows an extremely unpleasing performance.

```html
<html>
<style>
  div#divContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  div.toBeBlurred {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: crimson;
  }

  .blurred {
    filter: blur(25px);
    transition-duration: 2s;
  }
</style>

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById("applyBlurButton");
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("divContainer")

    btn.onclick = applyBlur;

    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.classList.add("toBeBlurred")
      divContainer.appendChild(newDiv)
    }
  }


  function applyBlur() {
    divContainer.classList.add('blurred');
  }
</script>

<body>
  <button id="applyBlurButton">Apply Blur!</button>
  <div id="divContainer">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Question/Request

- Do I miss something critical here? How to make filter blur animations work correctly in Firefox on modern machines? (see EDIT in **Result** section)

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, you haven't added the `transition` property anywhere, just the `transition-duration`. Change to `transition: filter 2s;` and it will work just fine.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, it does work! :) To quote myself: "Everything works as intended in Chromium and Safari, while the blur animation stutters in an awesomely ugly manner in Firefox." Just to be on the safe side, I put your suggestion in the example and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: If it "_stutters in an awesomely ugly manner in Firefox_" it obviously doesn't work. I checked this in FF and it works just fine, and the animation looks the same as in Chrome. The error with your posted code is that you use only one of the long hand properties, hence some browsers might act strange. And btw, Chrome is known to _fix/guess code syntax error_, so saying "it does work in Chrome" doesn't mean it works everywhere.

Comment: OMG. I switched from Mac to Windows and it magically works. I have absolutely no clue then how to make the UX consistent :[

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
.blurred {
  // Browser Specific
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -moz-filter: blur(25px);
    -o-filter: blur(25px);
    -ms-filter: blur(25px);
    filter: blur(25px);
    transition-duration: 2s;
  }
```

Comment: Don't post "try this" + code dump. It is a bad answer, not helpful without an explanation. Furthermore, it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not solve the problem. Especially, that prefix is not necessary for Firefox (in this case): https://caniuse.com/#search=filter, http://shouldiprefix.com/#filters